# ¿Como llamas a cada estilo de esa misma fuente?

Tags: css, font-faces

Lo comencé a codear al igual que vos, pero despues me di cuenta de que no puedo llamar individualmente a esa fuente con un estilo en particular. Por lo que opte por declarar la misma fuente con distintos estilos. En mi caso:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "CircularXX Book";
    src: url("../src/assets/font/CircularXX/CircularXX/CircularXX-Book.otf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "CircularXX Black";
    src: url("../src/assets/font/CircularXX/CircularXX/CircularXX-Black.otf");
}
```

Comment: Se necesita más i formación de lo estás queriendo lograr. Según entiendo, querés un estilo diferente de fuente para cada párrafo o texto ...?

Comment: No podés meter todas las familias en el mismo font-face. Está bien así separado.